# Pulseaudio Equalizer stuttering - samplerate problem?

Tags: linux, command-line, pulseaudio, pulseaudio-equalizer

I try to use pulseaudios built in equalizer in Ubuntu Touch with CLI.
I managed to got it working and hear the equalizer effect.
But when the equalizer is activated, the sound stutters.
I tried the several workarounds I found in the web: tsched=0, change msec size, resampling method, realtime-scheduling=no....
I also set default bitrate to s16le.

Nothing improved the sound quality.

Now I noticed, that I got a different sample bit rate between my equalizer sink and the connect master sink (primary output).
Primary Output is 16bit, while Equalizer is 32bit.
I tried to change equalizer with "pactl set-sink-formats 2 ..." but I dont know how to set ...
I found no hint how to write the last parameter.
"pactl set-sink-formats 2 s16le" doesnt work.
Maybe this would solve my stuttering sound problem?
Is there any other workaround I can try?
Its Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) on the phone.